# Error attached to the "Set-Cookie" attribute ⚠️

Tags: cookies, graphql, response, samesite, httpcookie

I am working on my headers for a couple of deployed applications, I attach a "Set-Cookie" attribute to a response from my server to my client (2 separate hosted domains). I see the Set-Cookie coming back in the Network response. It works fine locally, however, I get an error attached to the "Set-Cookie" attribute ⚠️ saying.

> The Set-Cookie didn't specify a "SameSite" attribute and was defaulted to "SameSite=Lax" and was blocked because it came from a cross-site response which was not the response to a top-level navigation. The Set-Cookie has to have been set with "SameSite=None" to enable cross-site usage

I have tried a few different syntaxes to achieve this, and have failed so far...
https://github.com/VolksRat71/NOT_SUPREME/blob/master/backend/src/resolvers/Mutation.js#L111-L115

So far I have tried...

```js
sameSite: "None"
>> option sameSite is invalid

SameSite: "None"
>> defaulted to "SameSite=Lax"

"SameSite" : "None"
>> defaulted to "SameSite=Lax"

"Same-Site" : "None"
>> defaulted to "SameSite=Lax"

"SameSite" : "none"
>> defaulted to "SameSite=Lax"
```

[Picture of Header in Frontend Deployed App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDxHa.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of Express in your `package-lock.json` file is Express v4.16.3. The "none" value for the `sameSite` option was added in Express v4.17.0.

You can delete your `package-lock.json` file and then re-run the npm installation with `npm i` - that will generate an up-to-date npm lockfile and it should have the latest version of Express.

You can then test and see if the `sameSite` option works. The option is spelled as `sameSite` (camelcase) and the value is `'none'` (lowercase).

Comment: You are the best! I finally after HOURS have a function application.